# Методы защиты от накруток

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Пишу тизерную сеть. Проверку по ip я знаю. Больше ничего в голову не лезет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть милый сайт **fairvote[dot]ru** если есть деньги то сервис позволяет отслеживать много чего полезного, в добавок к своим скриптам.

НУ а так запоминай и храни/отправляю

- IP адрес User-agent Отправленные
- куки отправленные юзверям
- Вход по логин/пароль(избавит многих ботов от голосования), тем более если на почту при регистрации падает письмо для подтверждения.

Но прощу заметить что!
Если пользователям влом региться на сайте то и кол-во голосов будет меньше, зато те кто зареген, будут в шоколаде.